# Grout between bathroom wall tiles cracked due to shifting walls; can polyurethane sealant be used to fill gap?

Tags: grout, crack, polyurethane

There is a gap/crack in the grout between two columns of wall tiles in the corner of my bathroom. I think it's because of the walls shifting in an earthquake in 1999 (I live in Athens, Greece). The tiles feel solid, and none are coming away from the wall.
I went to get grout from a hardware shop, to fill the crack, but the shop owner said I could use polyurethane sealant to fill it instead. I was a bit surprised by this. Is this true?

[image: close-up of crack]

[image: length of crack]

[image: roughly corresponding crack on outside wall, with filler]

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use some sort of a caulk to seal that gap, but that doesn't mean you should.

Tiles are usually grouted in the field, then corners are caulked, usually with a silicon-based caulk specifically designed for tub/shower use. Grout usually doesn't hold up well in the corners because of house movement, but it'll be fine in the field along one wall.

Buy your grout and regrout the tiles. Check other areas of the shower to make sure there aren't any loose bits of grout elsewhere. If there are, this is the perfect opportunity to remove them (use a "grout saw", designed to scrape the grout of of the joints), then apply new grout in these spots at the same time you're doing this grout line, too. You may want to use a grout sealer to keep it clean and help waterproof it. There are some grouts now that claim that they don't need to be sealed. I cannot vouch for their effectiveness. Then caulk in the corners.

Comment: Look for siliconized caulking made by the grout manufacturer in matching colors. In my experience, those are vastly easier to work with than a polyurethane.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; looks like I should grout the gap. And you say I should caulk the corner of the room, where the tiles meet? There is grout there, with no cracking, so I'd be putting the caulk over the top of that grout.

Comment: If you've got grout in the corners and it's currently in good shape, @openair, I'd leave it. Keep an eye on it, though and when it starts to crack, scrape it out with a grout saw then caulk the corner. Generally, corners (vertical, where tile meets tub, ceiling) are caulked because there tends to be more movement there than within a single wall.